Azure pipeline consume azure-pipelines.yml located in sub-directory
I have a git repo called comp_rep_qt, which uses git overlay mechanism and clones another repo.
- comp_rep_qt
    azure-pipelines.yml

When the pipeline is triggered, azure-pipelines.yml has scripts to clone another repo.
- comp_rep_qt
    azure-pipelines.yml
    execution (Note: another repo that is cloned using gitoverlay )
      - azure-pipelines.yml

Please suggest how to trigger azure-pipelines.yml within execution folder from azure-pipelines.yml of comp_rep_qt repo

As suggested in my answer below,  you can try to use the repositories resource and Templates in your YAML pipeline to reuse the stages/jobs/steps defined in another YAML file from another repository. @Yamuna

At the run-time of a pipeline, it is not supported to reference the steps in another YAML files to run.
If you want to reuse the stages/jobs/steps defined in another YAML file from another repository, I recommend you try repository resource and Templates.

Step reuse.
# Repository: repoB
# YAML file: stepTemplate.yml

steps:
- step1
- step2

# Repository: repoA
# YAML file: azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: resRepo
    type: git
    name: repoB
    ref: main

. . .
steps:
- stepA
- template: stepTemplate.yml@resRepo
- stepB

With above configuration, the pipeline (azure-pipelines.yml) in repoA will sequentially execute the following steps within the same job.
- stepA
- step1
- step2
- stepB


Job reuse.
# Repository: repoB
# YAML file: jobTemplate.yml

jobs:
- job1
- job2

# Repository: repoA
# YAML file: azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: resRepo
    type: git
    name: repoB
    ref: main

. . .
jobs:
- jobA
- template: jobTemplate.yml@resRepo
- jobB

With above configuration, the pipeline (azure-pipelines.yml) in repoA will execute the following jobs.
- jobA
- job1
- job2
- jobB


Stage reuse.
# Repository: repoB
# YAML file: stageTemplate.yml

stages:
- stage1
- stage2

# Repository: repoA
# YAML file: azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: resRepo
    type: git
    name: repoB
    ref: main

. . .
stages:
- stageA
- template: stageTemplate.yml@resRepo
- stageB

With above configuration, the pipeline (azure-pipelines.yml) in repoA will execute the following stages.
- stageA
- stage1
- stage2
- stageB




